# How to Zip mutiple files using Zend(2) Compress?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Files are getting zipped..but once i extracting the zip file, the result is single file..not a multiple file.How to zip multiple file using zend filter(Zip)..?

Here is my code..

```
//zip part
        $filter = new Compress(array(
            'adapter' => 'Zip',
            'options' => array(
                'archive' => TEMP_UPLOAD_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. "download" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $result['downloadResult']->r_download_id.'.zip'
            )
        ));
        $file_list = scandir(TEMP_UPLOAD_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. "download". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $result['downloadResult']->r_download_id);
        if(count($file_list) >2){
            foreach ($file_list as $file) {
              if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
              $filter->filter(TEMP_UPLOAD_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. "download". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $result['downloadResult']->r_download_id . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
            }
        }
        //zip end
```

Comment: Currently we have no idea if you are zipping files incorrectly or unzipping the files incorrectly. Show us some code

Comment: Yes..added my code..pls check

Comment: Does the resulting `zip` archive contain only the last file?

Comment: @gsc  Yes..it contains last file only..

Answer (score 1):

Every `$filter->filter(…)` invocation creates a new archive that contains only one file and the existing archive with the previous file gets overwritten. Solution:

```
$filter = new Compress([
  'adapter' => 'Zip',
  'options' => [
    'archive' => TEMP_UPLOAD_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'download'
      . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $result['downloadResult']->r_download_id . '.zip'
  ]
]);

// assuming you _can_ create archive from the whole directory
$filter->filter(TEMP_UPLOAD_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'download'
  . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $result['downloadResult']->r_download_id);
```

Comment: Anyway i have done it in core php..it's working.. code-------------- $zip->addFile(TEMP_UPLOAD_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. "download". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $result['downloadResult']->r_download_id . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file, $file);